# sp_oagetproperty fails when running using service broker

Tags: sql-server, web-services, sql-server-2008, service-broker

I have a stored procedure that calls a webservice and gets the response. Initially I had a problem with the responses that are greater than 4000 characters but then I found on the forums the trick of inserting the data into a temp table. This worked perfectly until I incorporated my SP into a db trigger that calls that SP though the service broker. The SP started to fail with an error that the XML is not structured, then I stored the response into a text value (as a log) and I saw that actually the response was again being limited to less than 4000 characters. It's very strange why the same SP works fine when I call it manually and it doesn't when I call it though the service broker. Below is the part from the SP that includes the process I am describing.

```sql
declare @obj int
,@responseXml xml
,@status nvarchar(50)
,@statusText nvarchar(1024)
,@method nvarchar(10) = (case when @HttpMethod in ('soap','SOAP') then 'POST' else @HttpMethod end)

exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj out
exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', null, @method, @Url, false

declare @host nvarchar(1024) = @Url
if @host like 'http://%'
set @host = right(@host, len(@host) - 7)
else if @host like 'https://%'
set @host = right(@host, len(@host) - 8)

if charindex(':', @host) > 0 and charindex(':', @host) < charindex('/', @host)
set @host = left(@host, charindex(':', @host) - 1)
else 
set @host = left(@host, charindex('/', @host) - 1)

declare @envelope nvarchar(max) = cast('' as nvarchar(max)) + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mob="http://mobility.sce.webservices.infor.com/"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><mob:{action}><String_1 xmlns="">{params}</String_1></mob:{action}></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'
declare @params nvarchar(max) = cast('' as nvarchar(max))

set @envelope = replace(@envelope, '{action}', @SoapAction)
set @envelope = replace(@envelope, '{params}', @ParamsValues)

set @SoapAction = @SoapAction

exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Host', @host
exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send', null, @envelope

DECLARE @responseText as table(responseText xml)

exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'responseXml', @responseXml OUTPUT
INSERT INTO @ResponseText (ResponseText) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseText'
exec sp_OADestroy @obj
```

I really appreciate your help as I am frustrated and can't find a solution for this.

Thanks in advance and please don't tell me to use CLR

Comment: Format the code

Comment: Would you please elaborate more ? What do you mean by Format the code please ?

Comment: It's 2019. Are you really trying to write web service calls using the archaic and brittle `sp_OA` stored procedures? Almost always, the better choice these days (**If** you think calling a web service from inside the database service in the first place is a good idea) would be via CLR.